# Would be welcome Health Care Market Research Opportunities?

Tags: discussion

Would some paid market research opportunities about health conditions be welcome in this community?
Patients and caregivers have the opportunity to take part in paid telephone interviews, focus groups, and online surveys. Participants receive generous compensation in exchange for their valuable time and input. Members of the panel also enjoy benefits such as staying current on the latest research and developments in the healthcare industry.

Answer (score 3):

No. A post like that would be considered spam and would be removed.